# Switching currency provokes 500 error

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account, error-log

Magento 1.9.3.4 frontend runs into that error only when a customer is logged in and tries to switch the currency with the currency switcher.
My error log shows:

> End of script output before headers: index.php, referer:
>   http://example.com/customer/account/login.

Can anybody help?